# is there a panel default for a LinkButton?

Tags: .net, asp.net, html

I was using  with a DefaultButton="searchButton" attribute.  I replace the button with and  is there a attribute to default to that link button? or is there another way?

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="searchButton">
     //New
     <asp:LinkButton id="searchButton" runat="server" OnClick="searchRedirect"> 
     <img alt="" src="images/SearchButton.png" style="margin:2px 0px 0px 10px; border:0px;" />
     </asp:LinkButton>
     //Old
     <asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" OnClick="searchRedirect" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try your OLD button with the image added via CSS :

```
<asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" OnClick="searchRedirect" CssClass="searchButton" />
```

with

```
.searchButton {
    background: url(../images/SearchButton.png) no-repeat left top;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use here  instead of  because when linkbutton render in html at that time it convert into  tag and a tag never works like a button.